# recovering from error

Tags: feature-request

I just visited the question-section, and opened some of them in - da-da-da-dam - 4 or 5 tabs.

Unfortunately, there was a server side error, and I got 4 or 5 tabs with the message:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/16652/prefix-every-argument-with-o-in-bash

I waited some minutes, for the error to vanish, and it vanished, but using 'reload' reloaded the errorpage, and since I opened them in tabs, I couldn't use the 'page back' button of the browser.

Since I didn't remember which question I had decided to visit, which I already visited (sometimes, they aren't what you expect from the headline, so the headline isn't always a help in remembering), and where to find them in the list, -- well, it's possible with hovering and the numbers, 16652 for example, but it's not comfortable.

A comfortable solution would be a link on the errorpage 'try again here in a few minutes' which reloads the requested page.

My suggestion, feature-request.

Comment: Does this still happen?

Comment: I hadn't had such errors in a while.